# Why isn't the current through the resistor equal to 1A?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

Current through the 1 Ohm resistor came out as 1A, however this is apparently incorrect.
[image]

Comment: Who says it's incorrect? And what do they say the correct answer is?

Comment: Apparently the correct answer is 0A, but I cannot see how to get to this answer

Comment: @konan091 The voltage across the 1-ohm resistor is one volt (it shares terminals with the voltage source), hence the current through that resistor is one ampere (apply branch constituent equation, in this case ohm's relation of V = IR). The "correct" answer appears to be incorrect, although the current through the *voltage source* is zero amperes.

Comment: Ah okay, that saves a lot of stress. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the question was about the current through the resistor and not the current through the voltage source?